# Confusion between conjunction and implication in a specific case

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

While writing following statement symbolically I ran into confusion.
U is the set of all integers.
1) All the primes are non-negative
let P(x) is used to express primes and N(x) for non negatives
then i came up with two solutions

1)  ∃x (P(X) ∧ N(X))

2)  ∃x (P(X) → N(X))

My Teacher says the second one is better but she cant explain the reason.Can someone explain

Comment: @AndréNicolas i have edited the question/

Comment: Your first statement is "there exists $x$ that is prime and non-negative" which is not the same as "all primes are non-negative"

Comment: @UmbertoP. i asked an explanation for that

Comment: The modified translations are both wrong. If you want to say all primes are non-negative and use $\exists$ you can write $\lnot \exists x(P(x)\land\lnot N(x))$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am asking for the explanation

Comment: @SayamQazi Explanation of what?

Comment: @GitGud I checked my 1st solution by putting different numbers and the results were correct then why i have to solve like the one which Andre proposed

Comment: The first says there is a number which is prime and non-negative. But that does not say **all** primes are non-negative. The second one (with implication) is also a mistranslation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so can you explain yours as you explained mine.

Comment: The natural translation is $\forall x(P(x)\to N(x))$. If we can't use $\forall$, we can use the fact that $\forall x A(x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot \exists x \lnot A(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher cannot explain why the second is better because *neither* given expression is right;   nor is either really less wrong that the other.

> All the primes are non-negative

This translates directly to a universally quantified statement: "If any integer is a prime, then it is non-negative"

$$\forall x\; (P(x)\to N(x))$$

That is close to your second attempt, except for the quantification.   If we are required to use existential quantifier instead of the universal, we apply *dual negation*.

$$\neg \exists x\;\neg(P(x)\to N(x))$$

Now, the negation of an implication is $\neg(A\to C) \equiv (A\wedge \neg C)$, (via implication equivalence and de Morgan's rule), so:
$$\neg \exists x \;(P(x)\wedge \neg N(x))$$

Which translates to "No integer is both prime and negative."

Which is close to your first attempt, except for the negation.

Thus both attempts are wrong.  The first is missing two negations, and the second has the wrong quantifier.